# Lazy loading image using IntersectionObserver and a high density pixel alternative. How to use both features with the same image?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to know how to apply lazy loading images with the IntersectionObserver and at the same time show high pixel density alternatives of these images for devices which require them.

Thank you in advance for any guidance provided.

This example below does not seem to work:

```
          <img class="lazyload" data-src="buttons-desktop-EN-1.jpg, buttons-desktop-EN-1@2x.jpg 2x">
```

```
const images = document.querySelectorAll('.lazyload');

function handleIntersection(entries) {
  entries.map((entry) => {
    if (entry.isIntersecting) {
      entry.target.src = entry.target.dataset.src;
      entry.target.classList.add("loaded");
      observer.unobserve(entry.target);
    }
  });
}

const observer = new IntersectionObserver(handleIntersection);

images.forEach(image => observer.observe(image));
```